# $.getJSON doesn't read my .aspx return

Tags: json, javascriptserializer, getjson

So I searched through most of the getJSON questions and am still unable to find a solution to my problem. My main problem is this: I have a .js file that makes a $.getJSON call to an .aspx page. The .aspx page returns a json object. I've tested the $.getJSON with a demo.js and it works just fine; I'm able to reference the json field. This is not the case with the .aspx page. Here is my code:

.js making the $getJSON call

```
$.getJSON('updateSlides.aspx', function (json) {
    alert("JSON Data: " + json.url);
});
```

.aspx returning json obj

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim jsonString As String
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim ws As New wallboardSettings
        ' pull data values from db here, replace hardcoded values below
        ws.duration = 5
        ws.imagePath = "Images\slide1.jpg"
        ws.url = "slide1.html"
        Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        jsonString = js.Serialize(ws)
        Response.Write(jsonString)
    End If
End Sub
```

I've placed a msgbox in the VB and ran it from my local machine to see my values. It returns the ws property settings in json form, which validated correctly on jsonlint.com.

I've also tried just using an $.ajax call with async: false but it doesn't work. When I use the demo.js, which works, i see the json fields in firebug; this is not the case with the updateSlides.aspx.

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Comment: Have you tried calling the aspx directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the json wasn't the issue. the aspx page was return json just fine. According to firebug the same aspx page was also returning addition html that was autogenerated. I deleted this html and firebug showed the json data. Thanks for your reponses!

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type headers to application/json from your response.